# Was James Gordon Jr Successful In His Mission At The End of Detective Comics 881?

Tags: dc, batman

I recently finished reading [The Black Mirror](http://www.dccomics.com/graphic-novels/batman-the-black-mirror) and the ending seems ambiguous.

In his conversation with Batman, James Gordon Jr implies that Batman may have been too late in stopping things...

> *James*: How do you know I didn't add the medication--because that's what it is, medication. A cure--How do you know I didn't add it to the infant formula days before you found the sample?  How do you know I haven't ALREADY DONE what I set out to do? You don't.  I guess you'll just have to wait a decade or two and see what Gotham looks like then!

Later, Dick Grayson and Jim Gordon discuss things:

> *Dick:* My honest opinion is that it's unlikely. There would've been greater residual material.
>  *Commissioner Gordon*: But it's possible.
>  *Dick*: It is.

In the final frame...

> We see a baby sleeping and then opening his/her eyes in a strange manner.

So my question is this: Is there any definitive in-universe proof that confirms what actually happened? Or is this entirely left up to the reader (and perhaps future stories)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is yet to be determined. While James Jr. has appeared a couple times in the New 52, as a member of the Suicide Squad, and during *Forever Evil*, his storyline from *The Black Mirror* hasn't advanced yet.

However, I did come across this tidbit while researching:

> James Gordon Jr. made a cameo - in Arkham Asylum - in the new Batman title by Scott Snyder **(*Batman Eternal*)**, who stated he plans to continue James' storyline that he started in his previous run on *Detective Comics*, saying "As for his presence in Gotham, he's someone I have some fun (dark and twisted) long-term plans for."

So, for now, I'd say the result of James Jr.'s mission is up to the reader. I, for one, look forward to seeing what happens with him in the future.